# How can I change the starting corner-point of the quiver?

Tags: matplotlib, parameters

Matplotlib.pyplot.quiver function uses coordinate systems with (0, 0) in the lower left and (1, 1) in the upper right corner. How can I change it into (0, 0) in the upper left and (1,1) in the lower right without changing my inputs?

Thank you for your time,

[image: question]

Comment: This question is ambiguous - there are two ways to map (0,0) -> (1,1) onto a line from corner to corner. Where do you want (1,0) or (0,1) to be?

Comment: `plt.ylim(350, 0)`?

Comment: In the image, it starts with (1,0) in the upper left corner end ends with (0,1) in the lower right corner. I want the coordinates to be like a matrix, starts with (0,0) in the upper left corner end ends with (1,1) in the lower right corner. Like a reflection over the x axis. Is it clear now? @AJ Biffl

Comment: No, @Sum. Where is (0,1), upper right or lower left?

Comment: lower left @AJBiffl, but I understood my mistake and found the answer, thank you.

Comment: Thank you @Stef. I also multiplied the input Y points by -1 to arrange the direction of the arrows.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.